# web3.eth.abi.decodeLog not finding an event argument

Tags: web3js, events, struct, abi

I have a [complicated event](https://goerli.etherscan.io/tx/0x7cf431d224a2c1656416321a5b3b13353796ac37a2c52083a35fa00809ab962b#eventlog) with the following signature:

`event SwappedShares(uint256 _stable, DataTypes.FeeReturn _fees, address _user, DataTypes.SubPoolGroup[] _subPoolGroups);`

Here are the datastructures involved:

```
    struct FeeReturn {
        uint256 totalFee;
        uint256 swapFee;
        uint256 lpFee;
        uint256 royalties;
        uint256 protocolFee;
    }

    struct SubPoolGroup {
        uint256 id;
        uint256 counter;
        uint256 total;
        AMMShare1155[] shares;
        SharesCalculationReturn sharesCal;
    }

    struct AMMShare1155 {
        uint256 tokenId;
        uint256 amount;
    }

    struct SharesCalculationReturn {
        uint256 PV;
        uint256 swapPV;
        uint256 amount;
        uint256 value;
        uint256 F;
        FeeReturn fees;
    }

    struct FeeReturn {
        uint256 totalFee;
        uint256 swapFee;
        uint256 lpFee;
        uint256 royalties;
        uint256 protocolFee;
    }
```

For some reason when I run `this.web3.eth.abi.decodeLog`, `totalFee` is not found in my event, even though it is definitely in the event data, and in the link I provided above it is the second row in the data. Here is the code I am running to decode the event:

```
    const decodedLog = this.web3.eth.abi.decodeLog(
            [
                {
                    type: "uint256",
                    name: "stableIn",
                    indexed: false,
                },
                FeeReturnDecoded,
                {
                    type: "address",
                    name: "_user",
                    indexed: false,
                },
                SubPoolGroups
            ],
            event.data,
            event.topics.slice(1)
        )
```

```
export const FeeReturnDecoded = {
    type: "tuple",
    name: "fees",
    components: [ 
        {
            type: "uint256",
            name: "totalFee"
        },
        {
            type: "uint256",
            name: "swapFee"
        },
        {
            type: "uint256",
            name: "lpFee"
        },
        {
            type: "uint256",
            name: "royalties"
        },
        {
            type: "uint256",
            name: "protocolFee"
        }
    ]
}
```

Am I parsing it wrong? Could this be a bug in web3.js? Thanks for reading